# Bootstrap button text not visible

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple `input-group` which contains a input-field and button.

The strange thing is, it doesn't show up. The color isn't the same as background-color, checked in inspect element.

I've created a JSfiddle, but that doesn't do anything, cause it shows perfectly there...

https://jsfiddle.net/u691aw17/

Maybe you guys have an idea?

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->

/* CSS */

div.input-group {
   width: 350px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;   
   font-size: 14px;
     input[type="text"]{
        width:300px;
        height:50px;
        font-size: 14px;
     }
     input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder{
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 14px;
     }
     input[type="text"]:-moz-placeholder /* Firefox 18- */
          {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 14px;
    } 
    input[type="text"]::-moz-placeholder /* Firefox 19+ */
          {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    input[type="text"]:-ms-input-placeholder{
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    span.input-group-btn button.btn {
        width:150px;
        height:50px;
        line-height: 1em;
        padding: 0px;
    }
}
.btn {
   background-color: green;
   color:#ffffff;
}

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn" type="button" >Sign up</button>
        </span>
    </div>


<!-- end snippet -->
```

[image: Problem]

[image: Element inspect]

Comment: I can see the button and I can see the input. What's wrong then?

Comment: I know, but I've copied exactly the code from my project, but it doesn't show the text there, I was hoping maybe some of you might know something.

Comment: and how do we know what the code in your project stopping you?

Comment: I can see the text aswell.

Comment: Clearly it is a problem with the rest of the styles because in Fiddler works perfectly. I'm guessing maybe the `font-size: inherit` is the problem? Try setting a font size to the button. You could also post the link to the full page to inspect it better.

Comment: @Gabriel Thanks! you were correct. If you want, you can place it as answer and I will mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly it is a problem with the rest of the styles because in Fiddle works perfectly.

I'm guessing maybe the `font-size: inherit` is the problem (it's inheriting font size 0 from its parent). Set a font size to the button to override that rule.

Answer (score 0):

Select button text not showing due to its padding. You can set height:auto to show the text of select button. Or set padding of select button to 0 (Zero) to see the text not appearing.

Answer (score -1):

I think it might be working in your fiddle because there's no Bootstrap CSS. You're trying to override the Bootstrap .btn class CSS, but with Bootstrap you often have to be more specific (as in specificity) than that. Add an id to the button and use that as your CSS selector.

Comment: That's a nonsense. You can't override showing placeholders and text inside the button with bootstrap, only the styling. And as he said, styling works for him. The thing is he doesn't see the text inside the input and inside the button.

Comment: Yes, the styling in inspect element is correct, but the text just doesn't show in my button.

Comment: But precise urself, what is not appearing, placeholder, text in the button or both?

Comment: Oh sorry, the text inside the button. The placeholder is showing correct. So: "Sign up"

Comment: Try to replace your `btn` code with `.btn {
 background-color: green !important;
 color:#ffffff !important;
}`

Comment: @K.Daniek The weird thing is, in inspect element it already says it has got the right properties (I just added some screenshots)